# reading tab delimited textfile java

Tags: java, file, text, tabs, delimiter

```
10
aaa aaa aaa
bbb bbb bbb
ccc ccc ccc
ddd ddd ddd
```

I have a textfile that Im trying to read with tab delimiters. whenever i read the file, i get an arrayindexoutofbound error after the 10. i search online and found that i have to add a -1 behind the \t but i still get the same error.

```
 try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("1.txt"));
        String line="";
        int readline = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());//

        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scan.nextLine();

            if(line.equals("ccc"))
            {  
                break;
            }
        String[] split=line.split("\t");

            array.add(split);
        }
```

Comment: Do you know, what the `break` statement does?

Comment: and why are you  using parseInt ? that is for getting int value out of a string.

Comment: there's obviously meant to be a number on the first line for whatever reason.

There's no where i can see in the cod eyou have posted that would result in an array index out of bounds. Can you post more code or the stack trace?

Comment: And it would be helpfull, if you say which function call throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace ? I mean the answer is pretty straightforward, but nobody can see a reason for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: @EarlGrey i want the scanning to stop after i get a string of ccc. srry its not aaa. im trying to get the value of 10 and skip it when i do the reading.

Answer (score 12):

If you are use `Scanner` here no need to `split`, you can use `next()` here as follows

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\test.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This way your code loses this ugly break (break are most of the time avoidable ...)

```
  try{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("1.txt"));
    String line="";
    int readline = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());//

    while (scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        line = scan.nextLine();

        if(!line.equals("aaa")){
           String[] split=line.split("\t");
           array.add(split);
        }
    }
```

And about your problem I think you are initializing your array with the integer on the first line but it is 10 and you have 12 elements. Thus the index out of bounds but your question remains unclear ...

Comment: Well I'm just following the example format, but yes you're right.

Comment: How do either of you know any of this, you don't know what he's trying to achieve. And none of it answers the question!

Comment: He wants to read "tab delimited text file" That is what it says in the title

Comment: Yes Glen is right I modified my answer
What I think is that the `array` Object is some kind of custom class based on an array. This undelying array is initialized with the first integer. The add function takes the String array `split` and add every element of it in the array.
OR he tries to add 12 elements in an array of lenght 10.

Comment: @Rakesh That's right, but there seems to be more then just reading. Why does he want to skip some lines? Where does the exception come from?

Comment: @EarlGrey Yes, because he has not posted the complete code, neither the stacktrace