# Saturday Night Java Fun with 2D arrays, and reading a text based tab delimited file to populate such an array

Tags: java, arrays, excel

Hey guys and gals hope everyones Saturday night is going as swimmingly (preferably more) than mine own.

I'm a java noob so bear with me.

We are told to export the an excel sheet from Open Office into a .txt (Tab Delimited) 
It ends up looking like this

```
1  2  3 
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
```

Where all values are separated by a tab.. (something I haven't encountered yet and are Integer values) 
I can see one option, as i type this as I could capture each line, then string split the line by?? whitespace or /t ... and then assign the values to the respective positions in the [30][10] array...

(which ends up being a .csv and load it into java.

So **Job 1** is to populate a 2D array with the files from the tab delimited file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Nitrogen
{       

private int elevations[][] = null;
private String filename = "location.txt";

public Nitrogen()
{   
    int [][]elevations = new int[30][10];

}


public void run()
{

    try{
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int rows = 30;
        int columns = 10;
        int[][] elevations = new int[30][10];

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            {
                if(input.hasNextInt())
                {
                    elevations[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                }
            }

            for (int h=0; h < rows; h++) {
                for (int g=0; g < columns; g++)
                    System.out.print(elevations[h][g] +" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening "+filename+", ending program");
        System.exit(1);}

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Nitrogen n = new Nitrogen();
    n.run();

} 

}
```

So, this prints out 30 lines of line 1, then a line of 0's on top of 29 lines of line 2, then 2 lines of 0's on top of 28 lines of line 3, You get the point....all moving left to right.

Not quite sure....tis getting late and i might give up for the evening.

**Alright!! Here is the solution... persistence pays of thanks for the help everyone**

```
        public void populate()
{

    try{
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int rows = 30;
        int columns = 10;
        int[][] elevations = new int[30][10];

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            {
                if(input.hasNextInt())
                {
                    elevations[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        for (int h=0; h < rows; h++){                   //This was just to show I had it
        for (int g=0; g < columns; g++) {               //in there correctly

                System.out.print(elevations[h][g] +" ");
            }
            System.out.println(""); }

    }

    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening "+filename+", ending program");
        System.exit(1);}

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using ArrayLists? They may be helpful in this case if the file needs to be changed. ArrayLists can increase and decrease in size based on the number of items needed.

If you need the tabs, I would check ASCII.

Comment: I do not need the tabs... Just the values. 
But they need to be in order as they are elevation data.  

It's an assignment for a class, so it doesn't need to be flexible past this example.

Comment: First, what does each line _represent_? If it can be meaningfully described by an object, do so. Second, use something from the `List` family rather than an array as you don't necessarily know how many lines you have. Third, either use a [library designed for reading delimited data](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or use `String.split` on each line, don't just whack it into a `Scanner` and hope for the best.

Comment: Hope for the best kind of describes my programming style....and made me laugh.  Thanks. 

Each line represents an elevation point basically it's an elevation map.  With a Valley in column 4 and descending sides of the valley from columns 0-3 descending by 8m from left to right, and columns 9-5 descending by 10m from right to left.  

I do know how big it is, it's [30][10]
So I'd like to read the first line exactly as it is then split it and parse it to integer like you're saying

Comment: Does OpenOffice provide xml of the sheet? If it does not provide an easy to parse format (based on the code above) how are you going to parse the data?

Comment: Good question... I have no idea.

Comment: I do know that based on example this is how I was supposed to save the file in OpenOffice, tab delimited.text ....for some reason it's still .csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading tab delimited textfile java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331696/reading-tab-delimited-textfile-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to print out the array, I would suggest the following amendment to your code:

```
for (int h=0; h < rows; h++) {
        for (int g=0; g < columns; g++)
            System.out.print(elevations[h][g] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
 }
```

The above will produce an output such as:
Row1, Row1, Row1
Row2, Row2, Row2

Because it prints out the columns, with a space in between each element, then a new line between the rows.

Comment: Ok So I did this, I get the same values...So obviously I am not putting it into the 2D array correctly.

Comment: Have you tried pre-populating the array (hard-coding it) and testing it? When I am stuck with Arrays, I find that creating a method that just populates the array with easy to track numbers, then printing it can solve most of the problems. Sometimes Java gets confused when reading in a new line. By doing this, you would be able to test your class to see if Java is just not reading on of your new lines correctly.

Comment: I haven't tried pre-populating it do you mean just throw in 300 random values? or just put it in manually.... the assignment is to read it in from the text file that was saved from open office using tab delimited (i specified extension, but it is a .csv nonetheless)

Comment: Yes, I would recommend a for loop that just populates it all with 0's. After it is done populating, you can test your functions and make sure they all work as expected. After you have debugged them, then I would recommend commenting out the for loop and trying to populate from the file. This type of debugging allows you to determine if it is a problem with the file, the data stream, or the surrounding code.

Comment: Ok cool.  So i commented out all the code and wrote a for loop to populate, then displayed it the same way as before, it now gives me 46 0's...

It looks like my for loop isn't populating the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a simple assignment for a class, but if you can use Collections for IO, please do so. It makes the code much more generally usable.

If you want to read values from a tab delimited file (in OpenOffice, this is called a `{Tab}` delimited CSV file in the Save dialog window), the easiest you can do, is split each line according to a tab, like this:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(); // list of lines
    String buffer;
    while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitted = buffer.split("\t"); // split the lines by tabs

        ArrayList<Integer> line = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str : splitted) {
            line.add(Integer.parseInt(str));  // cast and add all the integers to a list
        }

        list.add(line); // add the line to the list of lines
    }
    return list;
}
```

We are able to create a list of lines, with each line containing the Integer values from the text file. Now, we need to create a 2D list out of it, so concatenate all the values from every line to the line before.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> concatenateAll(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lines) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(); // create an empty 2D list for all the values
    for(ArrayList<Integer> line : lines) {
        result.addAll(line); // add all the values from every line to the 2D list
    }
    return result;
}
```

We can create a 2D list of all the values in the file. To use these two methods, we need to invoke them like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lineList = null;

    try {
        lineList = readFile("table.csv");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> allLines = concatenateAll(lineList);
    System.out.println(allLines);
}
```

If we absolutely need an array, we can add this at the end:

```
    Integer[] linesArray = new Integer[allLines.size()];
    allLines.toArray(linesArray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linesArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-class assignments, here's a one liner:

```cs
private string[][] Deserialize(string data)
{
  return  ( from string line
            in data.Split('\r\n')
            select line.Split(' ')
          ).ToArray();
}
```