# Swap two columns of a file in java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to write a method for swapping columns of a text file using java.

can someone show or tell me how to write a method to swap two columns of a file in java ? both columns are seperated by a space

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "give me the code" question, which is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: i just asked what can be the way..."i didn't asked for the code"... i wanted answer like "nbryans" gave me....

Answer (score 1):

One possible method:

- Read in file and split data (see here [reading tab delimited textfile java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331696/reading-tab-delimited-textfile-java))
- Overwrite file with same data read in, but column order switched.

Answer (score 1):

Read every line of the file

```
ArrayList<String[]> aryL = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for each line of file

    aryl.add(eachline.split(","));

for(String[] sArr: arrL)

    //Swap the elements and print or write to file
```

Answer (score 0):

you could read each line of a file and try

```
String buffer = "";
//for each line of input 
String[] columns = line.split(" ");
buffer+= columns[1] + " " + columns[0] + "\n";
//end for
```

then overwrite the file with your buffer String